# Add multiple properties during edge creation in gremlin

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have used this query

```
g.V().has('empId','123').as('a').V().has('deptId','567').addE('worksAt').properties('startedOn','17/15/07','title','manager','pay',15000)
```

which doesn't work.

Adding a single property works with a `.property` step

```
g.V().has('empId','123').as('a').V().has('deptId','567').addE('worksAt').property('startedOn','17/15/07')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of specifying all properties in one [`property`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addproperty-step)-step, you can simply concatenate multiple `property`-steps:

```
g.V().has('empId','123').as('a').V().has('deptId','567').addE('worksAt').
    property('startedOn','17/15/07').property('title','manager').property('pay',15000)
```

Your query doesn't specify which vertices should be connected by the edge. When you want the edge to go out from the vertex with the `empId` *123*, then you have to insert a `from`:

```
g.V().has('empId','123').as('a').V().has('deptId','567').addE('worksAt').from('a').
    property('startedOn','17/15/07').property('title','manager').property('pay',15000)
```

See the [`addEdge`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addedge-step)-step for more information.

Comment: What if I have a Map or a List of properties?

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 you mean you have a map where you want to store each key/value pair as a property? Or do you want to store a map/list as one single property where the map/list should become the value of the property? In case of the former, this was already answered a few times, for example [here][https://stackoverflow.com/q/68935172/6753576] and [here][https://stackoverflow.com/q/60602990/6753576].

Comment: The latter, and thank you.

Comment: Then it depends on your graph database whether that supports maps or lists directly as property values or not. For Neptune for example, this was already asked here for lists: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52737958/6753576
If you have problems with that, then please create a new question.