# Add a HashMap of Properties in Tinkerpop

Tags: java, gremlin, vertex, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a Map of Properties for Example:

```
map[0] = {
    ("name";"lux");
    ("lang";"german")
} 
map[1]= {
    ("name";"lux")
}
```

As you can see `map[1]` has no property "lang". Now I want to add a Vertex without hard Coding the keys.

Is there a way how I can do this in one Statement without looping the Map and add each property one by one.

Something like:

`Graph.addV("label").property(T.id, getID()).property(map,key,value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the basic Gremlin Console and TinkerGraph to produce this example but it should be no problem to express this in Gremlin Java.

```
nodes = [
    ["name": "Kim",    "breed": "Beagle"],
    ["name": "Max",    "breed": "Mixed"],
    ["name": "Toby",   "breed": "Golden Retriever"]]    

gremlin> g.inject(nodes).unfold().as("nodes").
......1>   addV("test").as("new_node").
......2>   sideEffect(select('nodes').unfold().as('kv').
......3>              select('new_node').
......4>              property( select('kv').by(Column.keys),
......5>                        select('kv').by(Column.values))).
......6>          id().toList()    
==>9
==>12
==>15               

gremlin> g.V().valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)
==>[id:9,label:test,name:[Kim],breed:[Beagle]]
==>[id:12,label:test,name:[Max],breed:[Mixed]]
==>[id:15,label:test,name:[Toby],breed:[Golden Retriever]]
```