# Gremlin how to add multiple properties from a java collection

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a map of properties `Map<String, String> properties`

and the following code to add an edge with the given propeties

```
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Edge> traversal = from.graph().traversal().V(from).as("from").V(to).addE(edgeLabel).from("from");
    properties.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> traversal.property(key, properties.get(key)));
    traversal.next();
```

Is it possible to do it in one line? Is there a better way to add multiple properties from a java collection?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it's easiest to include the `Map` as a side-effect and then unfold it into it's key/value pairs so that you add them via `property()`:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> m = ["weight": 0.9d, "something":"anything"]
==>weight=0.9
==>something=anything
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('m',m).
......1>   V(1).as('from').V(6).addE('knows').from('from').as('e').
......2>   sideEffect(select('m').unfold().as('kv').
......3>              select('e').
......4>              property(select('kv').by(keys), select('kv').by(values)))
==>e[13][1-knows->6]
gremlin> g.E(13).elementMap()
==>[id:13,label:knows,IN:[id:6,label:person],OUT:[id:1,label:person],weight:0.9,something:anything]
```

Comment: thanks but I prefer the original code as it much more readable